# Non HTTP response code: java.net.ConnectException in JMeter

Tags: amazon-ec2, jmeter

I am new to JMeter. I have created one script for our application. Now our complete system architecture is deployed on AWS. So, we have created one EC2 instance as `"Load Generator"` to run my script with 100 user load. Script is working fine on my local system but it is not working on that instance.

Every time I am getting below error. I have also tried to run from non-GUI mode as well but result is same.

> **Error:**  Response code: Non HTTP response code: java.net.ConnectException Response message: Non HTTP response message:
>   Connection timed out (Connection timed out)

Please help me out here. How to resolve this issue on EC2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem (my tests were executed on Microsoft's Azure).
The issue was that the system being tested had a **IP white list**.

- When I ran it on my local machine, it was already within our VPN
  (whitelisted).
- When it was executed on Azure, the VM had a
  dynamic IP which was not whitelisted.